# AWS Lambda: Java Integration testing

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, integration-testing

Is there way to build proper integration test for few AWS Lambdas interacting each other via AWS SNS topic?

I deployed two lambdas using Java.

- The first one is subscribed to AWS SNS_topic#1. It filters and transforms SNS message and pushes modified data onto SNS_topic#2.
- The second one lambda is subscribed to SNS_topic#2. It modifies SNS message and do http request onto external endpoint.

I need to build end-to-end Integration test to check whole interaction.

Comment: Add some more detail with complete scenario. I can surly help you in this.

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal Thank you for attention. I added additional information into main question.

Comment: You just need to add some notification for which you are filtering and whole flow will execute automatically. Isn't it?

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal Yes. Finally, I need to build complex end-to-end local test. So, I need to emulate SNS topic with lambda subscription to test proper work of both lambdas in ineraction.

Comment: Gogol no need to build any complex solution please go through my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the amazon-cli if you want to test it from your local.

amazon-cli will help you to manually trigger your lamda via aws lambda invoke the command.

Please install amazon-cli at your local from [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/setup-awscli.html).

After that you can invoke the amazon 1st lamda from your cli with aws lamda command. It comes with many options like you can pass payload (supposed to be pass from SNS in actual scenario).

[Executing AWS Lamda from Amazon-CLI Command details description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-userapp-walkthrough-custom-events-invoke.html)

Example command:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name your_function_name --invocation-type RequestResponse outfile.txt --payload file:requestFile.txt
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. as I understand: there is no way to build old planed automation integration tests...

Comment: @MihailGogol So for lambda can't we write normal integration testing we write for java project?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a better way, you should check out the
https://github.com/localstack/localstack
and https://github.com/localstack/localstack-java-utils
This two tools will help you to test your serverless apps built on AWS